# how to change node submit form text for all users?

Tags: 8, forms, actions

I created the node type 'application',which can be added by any users and will be unpublished by default.
   I used `hook_form_id_alter()` to change the text of the submit button as below:

```
 function custom_module_form_node_application_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 


         //   to change the text of the button
          if (isset($form['actions']['publish'])) {
            unset($form['actions']['publish']);
          } 
       if(isset($form['actions']['unpublish'])) {
           $form['actions']['unpublish']['#value'] = 'Apply';
       }
}
```

**It is updating the button text,only when I logged in as admin, but  for anonymous users and others submit button text is 'Save' instead of 'Apply'.**

Comment: Just a guess, maybe an anonymous user has no permission to publish and therefore the two actions buttons publish/unpublish are not present.

Comment: yes.He don't have permission to publish.. I'll check other $form['actions'] path